Upgrading Deprecated Apply Script Method
I've been trying to get rid of the warning I get when running an old Flutter project, and I've tried to migrate my project using the official instructions. However, whenever I finish the process, I get this error in my Android/build.gradle file.

The Java Build Status terminal shows that the reload has been completed.
Everything on the files I changed looks completely fine.
app/build.gradle:
plugins {
    id "com.android.application"
    id "kotlin-android"
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-gradle-plugin"
}

def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

android {      

    compileSdkVersion flutter.compileSdkVersion
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.livit"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
        multiDexEnabled true
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

settings.gradle:
pluginManagement {
def flutterSdkPath = {
    def properties = new Properties()
    file("local.properties").withInputStream { properties.load(it) }
    def flutterSdkPath = properties.getProperty("flutter.sdk")
    assert flutterSdkPath != null, "flutter.sdk not set in local.properties"
    return flutterSdkPath

}()

includeBuild("$flutterSdkPath/packages/flutter_tools/gradle")

repositories {
    google()
    mavenCentral()
    gradlePluginPortal()
}
}

plugins {
    id "dev.flutter.flutter-plugin-loader" version "1.0.0"
    id "com.android.application" version "7.2.0" apply false
    id "org.jetbrains.kotlin.android" version "1.8.0" apply false
}

include ":app"

Android/build.gradle:
allprojects {
    repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
    }
}

rootProject.buildDir = '../build'
subprojects {
    project.buildDir = "${rootProject.buildDir}/${project.name}"
}
subprojects {
    project.evaluationDependsOn(':app')
}

tasks.register("clean", Delete) {
    delete rootProject.buildDir
}

Does anyone see what I'm doing wrong? I've tried everything from deleting the Android folder and just running flutter create again, removing plugins that were giving me errors like gms, uninstalling/reinstalling VS Code (For a while I thought VS Code was the issue because the error didn't seem to pop up on another machine). Thanks in advance!
